# Spring Exception handler return list of errorcodes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I return the `List<DataStruture>` error codes in a spring `ExceptionHandler` class? I tried the below code:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ CustomException.class })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public List<ErrorOutDTO> handle(CustomException theException) {
    return new null;
}
```

I was struck at the return type of a method.

Comment: can you clarify, what do you want to achieve with this 1. Controller method sends multiple HttpStatus codes 2. CustomException.class `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, HttpStatus.OK)` ?

Comment: use @RestControllerAdvice on class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind List of errors in [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) and then return it.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorOutDTO>> validationExceptionHandler(CustomException exception) {
        List<ErrorOutDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ErrorOutDTO error = new ErrorOutDTO();
        error.setField(exception.getField());
        error.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
        list.add(error);
        return (ResponseEntity<List<ErrorOutDTO>>)new ResponseEntity(list, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

Comment: this dont override the default response for me :(

Answer (score 0):

For example, if exception is ConstrainViolationException: This exception reports the result of constraint violations

```
@ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(
  ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        errors.add(violation.getRootBeanClass().getName() + " " + 
          violation.getPropertyPath() + ": " + violation.getMessage());
    }

    ApiError apiError = 
      new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), errors);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
      apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}
```